# trying to use Float.parseFloat() in android but my IDE not recognizing parseFloat

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

Im trying to set rating in rating bar while the API service returns a sting for rating field. couldn't find any way to use it directly in xml using databinding so I tried binding adapter and surprisingly the `parseFloat` in `Float.parseFloat()` is not recognizing by my IDE. I have tried this piece of code in other part of project like fragments but nothing happens.
Thanks for any idea and suggestion.

Comment: have you tried invalidate cache / restart

Comment: @Shayan I tried after you said but still is not working. tnx anyway.

Comment: The usual reason for this kind of thing is that you have your own class called `Float`. If this is the case, don't.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Kotlin doesn't have Float.parseFloat() method.

To convert string to float use toFloatOrNull(), this will convert string to float

```
var string = "5" 
var floatNumber = string.toFloatOrNull()
Log.e(TAG, " string.toFloatOrNull() $floatNumber")
```

You can set this float value in rating bar

Comment: Doesn't answer the question that was asked, which was why 'Float.parseFloat()` wasn't recognized. =